# PHP_Incomplete_Class Object / Different responses from print_r

Tags: serialization, php

When I issue a print_r ($_SESSION) on my local server I receive the following

```
Array
(
    [group] => Rich Primosch
    [ok] => 1
    [golfer] => Fritz Davis
    [uniq] => 38
    [fname] => Fritz
    [lname] => Davis
    [hphone] => 352-487-0597
    [cphone] => 352-487-6189
    [email] => fritz@hadleyvillage.org
    [vid] => 527571
    [handicap] => 23
    [admin] => 0
    [page] => signup.php
)
```

However when I issue the same print_r ($_SESSION) on the webhost's server I get this response

Array
(

```
 [group] => __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object
        (
            [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => window
            [curdate] => 1293771600
            [datetime] => 1293813211
            [monplay] => 1294030800
            [wedplay] => 1294203600
            [friplay] => 1294376400
            [monclose] => 1293750000
            [wedclose] => 1293922800
            [friclose] => 1294030740
            [monopen] => 1293426000
            [wedopen] => 1293426000
            [friopen] => 1293426000
            [ismonopen] => 
            [iswedopen] => 1
            [isfriopen] => 1
        )

    [ok] => 1
    [golfer] => mysqli_result Object
        (
        )

    [uniq] => 175
    [fname] => Fritz
    [lname] => Davis
    [hphone] => 352-487-0597
    [cphone] => 352-487-6189
    [email] => fritz@hadleyvillage.org
    [vid] => 723234
    [handicap] => 23
    [admin] => 0
    [page] => signup.php
)
```

Why I even see the incomplete class object, I have no idea.  It is never assigned to a $_SESSION variable and yes, the class definition is included before session_start().

There are several differences in the two responses.  My question is why?  Is there a difference in settings somewhere or is there a programming error.

I have seen many references to the PHP_Incomplete_Class Object but they all say make sure that the class definition proceeds session_start.  In my case it does but that should be inconsequential because I only use the object on one page and do not store it in a session.

Suggestions are appreciated.

-dmd-

Comment: Try turning session.auto_start of within the ini if your doing this manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try var_dump instead in both machines, it may say something interesting, "group" value seems to be an object, of what type? does it have a __sleep() magic method?
ensure your test machine  and production server has the same php version to better understand the issue.
@see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php